# Deserialize JSON into custom c# object list

Tags: c#, json, .net

From the api call:

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 var uri = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/";
 var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, data);
 string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoDataList>(result);
```

with two custom classes:

```
  [Serializable]
    public class GeoData
{
    [JsonProperty("postcode")]
    public string postcode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public string longitude { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public string latitude { get; set; }
}

    public class GeoDataList
    {
        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public List<GeoData> geoDatas { get; set; }
    }
```

The result contains this json-string:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "result": [{
    "query": "OX49 5NU",
    "result": {
      "postcode": "OX49 5NU",
      "longitude": -1.069876,
      "latitude": 51.6562
    }
  }, {
    "query": "M32 0JG",
    "result": {
      "postcode": "M32 0JG",
      "longitude": -2.302836,
      "latitude": 53.455654
    }
  }, {
    "query": "NE30 1DP",
    "result": {
      "postcode": "NE30 1DP",
      "longitude": -1.439269,
      "latitude": 55.011303,
    }
  }]
}
```

The list contains 3 empty objects. postcode, longitude, and latitude are null.
How do I populate the inner objects (GeoData)?

Kind regard
/Rudy

Comment: Are you expecting all those 3 inner `"result"`s to end up in your one outer C# object as direct descendants of it? Your C# class structure doesn't map to the json structure..

Comment: There are 2 `result` properties the list and in list's item , your model class is obviously wrong

Comment: @Rudy W [check this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M3keCA) example out, your `GeoData` class definition is wrong and doesn't match the `json`.

Comment: In addition to what I noted below, jut wanted to let you know (in case you weren't aware) that many JSON-emitting APIs these days have a swagger/openapi definition available; this is a bunch of JSON that describes everything the service does, all the objects it consumes and emits, what all the endpoints are called etc.. Why is that interesting to you? Well, you can use some tool like NSwagStudio, AutoRest etc, and say to the tool "here is the swagger/openapi definition file" and it will literally then write *everything* else for you; you get a client class that you use like..

Comment: `var c = new PostcodesClient("https://api.postcodes.io"); var result = c.GetLatLong(some_query_data_here);` and that's it, the result you wanted. NSwag et al write all the http client code, the de/ser code everything - it makes using an API about as easy as adding a DLL reference, making a new object and calling it's methods.. When you have an API you wanna use, try and find out its openapi endpoint. In this case see https://github.com/ideal-postcodes/openapi

Comment: (It's wonderful; like going back in time 15 years to the days of SOAP, WSDL and ASMX/WCF.. the hardest part of using a webservice was figuring out what MS had renamed VS's "Add Service Reference" option to this week :D :D )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, when we have to work with JSON and we really don't want to grunt all this out by hand, because it's tedious and liable to error, we go to http://quicktype.io (or json2csharp, or some similar site) and we paste our JSON in there..

We fix up any syntax errors in the json (quicktype shows a red bar in the json-paste window), like the trailing comma on the last result latitude, and we get this bunch of classes generated by QuickType:

```
// <auto-generated />
//
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using SomeNamespace;
//
//    var root = Root.FromJson(jsonString);

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public long Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public ResultElement[] Result { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ResultElement
    {
        [JsonProperty("query")]
        public string Query { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public ResultResult Result { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ResultResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("postcode")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("longitude")]
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("latitude")]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Root
    {
        public static Root FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Root self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, SomeNamespace.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

And the comment at the top tells us how to use it:

```
var root = Root.FromJson(jsonString);
```

And then if you just want the inner result objects you could:

```
root.Result.Select(r => r.Result).ToList()
```

If you don't like the class names that QT has picked, you can refactor/rename them in VS - the json will remain parsable because it also added all the `[Jsonproeprty]` attributes for you with the names as per the JSON so the C# props can be anything you like

QT is Newtonsoft oriented; if you want to use the generated classes with `System.Text.Json` you just have to adjust the attribute names with find/replace and a couple of other bits of tidy up

<sub>I have zero affiliation with QT</sub>

Comment: *Or we can do it in VS*.... :)

Comment: True, QuickType does have a VS extension with even more features! (teasing; secretly I know^H^H^H^Hsuspect you're talking about "Paste JSON as Classes", but it doesn't loop in the type converter stuff, or the convenience methods for ser/deser, nor does it offer customization over the generated results, but it's a reasonable halfway house..)

Comment: Yes, agree Caius. There are also extensions that can be installed to do this as well, no need to dump json online to get the definitions.

Comment: Totally agree, I'm just a lot more happy to recommend "go to this website, paste this and look at what you get" than I am to "if you just install this software into your VS, which is maybe running as admin...". Worthy point though (and noted in the comments on the Q)